# Using Leaflet plugins on react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, plugins, leaflet

I am building a ReactJs application with react-leaflet.
Problem is that there are a lot of Leaflet plugins that has no support for react-leaflet.

I try to use this plugin
http://kartena.github.io/Leaflet.zoomslider/

Can somebody suggest a solution in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Leaflet plugins don't have a React component. You can [create custom components](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html) for React-Leaflet from the Leaflet plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say you do it by getting a reference to the map object, but I don't think that's needed. But I have left that in at the base of this response as it a very helpful thing to know.

try the following:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
          zoomsliderControl: true,
          zoomControl: false,
          layers: [layer]
      }).setView([57.7, 11.9], 8);
```

Where 'map' is the id of the Map element.

===========================================
On your Map element get a reference to the map object.

```
<Map ref={(m) => this.leaf = m} etc...>
```

then in your react component.
where you have componentDidMount= () =>{

use the map object to add in the slider

```
var map = this.leaf.leafletElement;
```